# A function to run a multiple pieces of code

Tags: python, function, email

I was working on creating a dataframe from a SQL query and then indexing and changing the datetime format of a column, at the end I want to send an email. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to write a function to all the jobs.

The overall goal is to send an email notification to customers.

Below is the piece of code I have written, I would like to make it short.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df=pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
now=datetime.datetime.now()  
dis=display(df)
print("Job last ran on: {} ".format(now))
```

This is for the later part, where I would like to send out an email.

```
df_html= df.to_html(index= False)
HTML(df_html)
sendHtmlMail(df_html)
pause.seconds(1800)
time.sleep(1800)
```

something like this

```
def main():
    df=pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
    now=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    df_html= df.to_html(index= False)
    HTML(df_html)
    sendHtmlMail(df_html)
    display(df)
    print("Job last ran on: {} ".format(now))
    if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think this did the job, please let me know if there is a better way to do it.                                                                                       def main():
    df=pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
#     now=datetime.datetime.now()
    df_html= df.to_html(index= False)
    HTML(df_html)
    sendHtmlMail(df_html)
    pause.seconds(60)
    time.sleep(60)
    
if __name__== "__main__":
        main()

Comment: How is this pandas?

Comment: sorry, it was a pandas data frame, I thought I will put pandas as a keyword. I changed the keyword to just function.

Comment: NO worries @Vishaws

Answer (score 1):

This may be the extremely simple question, but you may call functions inside functions.

```
def fmain():
    f1();
    f2();
```

Where `f1`and `f2` actually do some specific actions. 
Let me know if this works for you?

If you may check for [async/await](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) functions though, this definitely may be part of your task.